# JS hint errors on jsfiddle -how to decipher and debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jsfiddle, jslint

I am getting jshint errors on a fiddle but can't figure out why. When I extract the snippets that are causing an issue and test on jslint.com there are no warnings or errors. Am I doing this in an incorrect manner. I am basically wanting to log arguments in the jsfiddle view so I can see what is going on, and get a clearer picture of how functions operate.

```html
function fakeReplace(data, substr, newstr) {
    div.append("data before match replace = " + data);
    div.append("\<br>");
    div.append("substr = " + substr);
    div.append("\<br>");
    div.append("newstr = " + newstr);
    div.append("\<br>");

    return data.map(function (s) {
        return s.split(substr).join(newstr);
    });

}
```

[the fiddle in question](http://jsfiddle.net/dntreply/pc8y5un5/13/)

Comment: drop your code into http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ it will tell you the jshint errors if you hover over the caution signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is producing jshint errors because `<` does not necessarily need to be escaped.

The regular expression in your fiddle is triggering it because it wants to encourage wrapping your regular expressions in parentheses (e.g. `(/""/g).test(x)`).